# Trying MD5 Hash in java

Tags: java, hash, message-digest

Hi I have written a class to create a hash for a String input but my Program sometimes give same hash for two different input.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


public class Test {

public byte[] Hash(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte b[] = messageDigest.digest(input.getBytes());
    return b;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
   Test t = new Test();
   byte[] hashValue = t.Hash("viud");
   String hashString = hashValue.toString();
   while(hashString.length()<32)
   {
       hashString = "0" + hashString;
   }
   System.out.println(hashString);
}

}
```

When my input to the function Hash() is **"viud"** the I am getting result as --> 0000000000000000000000[B@13e8c1c
And when my input String is **"Hello"** then also I am getting result as --> 0000000000000000000000[B@13e8c1c

But this case is happening only few times on program execution.
Every time I am running the Program,I am getting different hash generated for the same input value and also sometimes getting same hash value for two different inputs.

What happens exactly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   byte[] hashValue = t.Hash("viud");
   String hashString = hashValue.toString();
```

toString on a byte[] will give you the memory (heap) address of the byte[]. This isn't what you want. You want

```
String hashString = new String(t.Hash("viud"));
```

Comment: using String hashString = new String(t.Hash("viud")) will give me Unique hash for every input? @ControlAltDel

Comment: @VidhiAgarwal No, hashes can't be unique because you are mapping an infinite number of inputs to a sequence of 16 bytes (for MD-5).

Comment: @VidhiAgarwal No. No hash code algorithm produces unique hashes.

Comment: I tries your soln but getting output now as -- 0000000000000000]A@*¼K*v¹q?‘Å’
@ControlAltDel

Comment: @VidhiAgarwal you may have to add a second parameter to new String(...) to define the text format (i.e. ascii, utf-8/16, latin-1, etc)

Comment: If hashes can't be unique then what is the importance of hashes? @AlexR

Comment: Is there a way to generate unique hash for ever input? I want to use hash for login page for secure login. @AlexR

Comment: @VidhiAgarwal For that, you should use a so called _salt_. You could read [this article](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). And if you really want to do that, you probably shouldn't use MD5..

Comment: @VidhiAgarwal MD5 can be used for the same purposes that checksum used to be used for

Comment: @VidhiAgarwal If the requirement is that the hash must be unique, compressing the document using gzip is information-wise about as good as you are going to get